# Getting Mingw32 on windows 10 to recognize libcurl

Tags: mingw, libcurl, mingw32

I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Missing required libcurl dev >= 7.25.0
```

The guide I am using is pasted below. It says to download libcurl from the "Win32 - Generic" section of the [site](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and copy the bin, lib, and includes contents from the unzipped folder to my \MinGW\bin, \MinGW\include, and \MinGW\lib.

perceived problem I am having:

1) I am not able to find a download that has the: "bin", "include" and "lib" all included in a single zip file. I basically find a "bin and a "lib" folder. I have tried them all of the downloads under "Win32 - Generic."

> - Install libcurl                                                                    *
>
> ---
>
> Go to this url ==> http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32
>
> At the section where it says "Win32 - Generic", Click on the link that
>   indicates
>
> Win32 2000.XP 7.xx.x libcurl SSL and download it.
>
> Extract the files that are in the zip (bin, include, and lib) to their
>   respective
>
> locations in MinGW (\MinGW\bin, \MinGW\include, and \MinGW\lib).
>
> Edit the file \MinGW\lib\pkgconfig\libcurl.pc and search for the line
>   that ends
>
> with "-lcurl", and make it say "-lcurl -lcurldll".

Ref. http://old.nabble.com/gcc-working-with-libcurl-td20506927.html

Can anyone tell me where I may be going wrong? or has anyone used the libcurl before and shed some light on how they made it work. Any input is appreciated.

Also when I type libcurl in my Mingw32 terminal. It recognizes it.  by that I mean it does not give me the libcurl.dll not found error. I have put the libcurl.dll and the libcurl executable in the same file.